# Counting the amount of 0's in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, count, boolean-logic

I wanted to count the amount of zero/false in my table because the `en_participation` is a `Boolean` variable. But I looked up and when I replace the `0` for `1` in the `SELECT` statement it works correctly but, when I replace it to `0` it gives me the same result.

any help would be appreciated

```
SELECT count(CASE WHEN en_participation THEN 0 END) FROM Enrolls
```

Comment: Hi please edit the question and post a [mcve] including table definition and example data

Comment: change count to sum.  weather you count 1 or 0, the count will be the same.  if you SUM 1 or 0.  it will make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't tell it what to do in the case where things don't match:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE
               WHEN not en_participation
                 THEN 0
                 ELSE NULL
             END) AS TOTAL_COUNT
  FROM Enrolls
```

Zero is a countable value. NULL is not.

[See this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3486924c86daf52a8520cd554b318e13)

### EDIT

After a night to think about it I'm amending my answer. There was nothing wrong with it, but it wasn't as good as it could be.

The problem in the question and my original answer is that it's not clear exactly what's being counted. We're counting FALSE's, yes - but in the case where `en_participation` is FALSE we return 0, and while this *is* a countable value it's easy to misinterpret it. Therefore, I came up with the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE en_participation
               WHEN true THEN 1
               WHEN false THEN NULL
             END) AS TRUE_COUNT,
       COUNT(CASE en_participation
               WHEN true THEN NULL
               WHEN false THEN 1
             END) AS FALSE_COUNT
  FROM Enrolls
```

[See this db<>fiddle for the improved answer](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5daa716367f690a14f6f8a95fb80555d)

The question and my original answer also return 0 as the countable value. This is correct, but it can be confusing at first glance. My updated answer returns 1 for the countable rows which I think is better.

(For those who wonder, "How does this guy have time for this?" - I'm at home recovering from knee replacement surgery so I'm bored and I hurt, making this a nice distraction. :-)

Comment: `ELSE NULL` is the default; if you leave it out, the case will still produce NULL.  But it doesn't hurt and some may find it more clear with it in.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to count the 0s is by summing:

```
SELECT SUM(NOT en_participation) AS count_zeros,
       SUM(en_participation) AS count_ones
FROM Enrolls
```

Here, the expression `NOT en_participation` changes 0s to 1s and 1s to 0s